# How can I make the images I gather into a "instagram" listview?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Right now when I gather my data (the images) I get 3 of the same image in the same row. I want the image to gather inside my listview by laying next to eachother (3 unique images on each row) and then move down a row.

This is my current code:

```
new List<info> imagesList = new List<info> ();

protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        imagesListview.RowHeight = (int)(this.Width / 3);
    }

async void loadPhotos ()
    {
        var getInfo = await phpApi.getPhotos ();

        imagesListview.ItemsSource = null;
        imagesList = new List<info> ();
        foreach (var items in getInfo["results"]) {

            imagesList.Add (new info () {
                theimage = items ["Photo"].ToString(),
                theimage2 = items ["Photo"].ToString(),
                theimage3 = items ["Photo"].ToString(),
            });
        }
        imagesListview.ItemsSource = imagesList;


    }

   public class info 
    {
        public  string theimage {get; set;}
        public  string theimage2 {get; set;}
        public  string theimage3 {get; set;}

    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="imagesListview" RowHeight="100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.75" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                      <ViewCell.View>
                            <AbsoluteLayout>
                                <Image Source="{Binding theimage}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding theimage2}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding theimage3}"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0, 0.0, 0.333, 1.0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect = "AspectFill" />
                            </AbsoluteLayout>
                      </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Your info class needs to be able to reference three different images that you can bind against.  When you build your List<info> you will have to break up your images in groups of three.

Comment: so create 3 different images strings and do this: `theimage = items ["Photo"].ToString(), theimage2 = items ["Photo"].ToString(), theimage3 = items ["Photo"].ToString()` and them bind them to each one in XAML?

Comment: I have this snippet of code as well by the way: `protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        imagesListview.RowHeight = (int)(this.Width / 3);
    }`

Added it to the post as well

Comment: I tried what I wrote to you above but that did not solve it. I am not quite understanding you correctly and what I need to do

Comment: You're using `theimage` as the source for all 3 images in each row. See the `<Image Source="{Binding theimage}" ...` in your XAML? That means all 3 images have the SAME source. How could you get a different images when using the same source? Add 2 more properties in `info` to hold a total 3 different images (so `theimage', `theimage1`, and `theimage3` but please use better names). Then when you create your `imagesList` with `info` objects, put 3 different images in each `info` object.

Comment: Check my updated post now. I still get 3 pictures on the same row when I adjusted the code. I guess I am missing something

Comment: when you create the new info object you are assigning the same value to all three properties

Comment: you mean when I create the 3 different public strings inside the class? or are is the issue inside the foreach loop?

Comment: inside the foreach

Comment: So I have to create 3 different tables in my backend? "Photo", "Photo2", "Photo3"? Sorry if I am being slow. But how would that work if a user wants to add an image themselves? A bit tricky if you have to add that image into one of the three categories?

Comment: I am going to assume `getInfo["Results"]` is an array or list type. You want to pull 3 items from that, and put all 3 into the 3 properties of `info`. You need to do something more advanced than just foreach and add an `info` for each photo. 1 `info` = 1 list row = 3 *different* photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ndx = 0;
Info info = null;

foreach (var items in getInfo["results"]) {

  if (ndx == 0) {
    info = new Info();
    info.theimage = items ["Photo"].ToString();
    ndx++;
  } else

  if (ndx == 1) {
    info.theimage2 = items ["Photo"].ToString();
    ndx++;
  } else

  if (ndx == 2) {
    info.theimage3 = items ["Photo"].ToString();
    imagesList.Add(info);
    info = null;
    ndx = 0;
  }
}

if (info != null) {
  imagesList.Add(info);
}
```

Comment: still 3 in the same row. sec will experiment some more

Comment: Yea I copy your code and get 3 of the same image in a row still.

Comment: you need to debug your code and verify that each item is really a unique URL, and that they are getting grouped together in info properly

Comment: The json that I am working with is looking exactly like this:
`{
results: [
{
ID: "1",
Photo: ”16323120/one.php"
},
{
ID: "2",
Photo: ”16323120/two.php"
},
{
ID: "3",
Photo: ”16323120/three.php"
},
{
ID: "4",
Photo: ”16323120/four.php"
},
{
ID: "5",
Photo: ”16323120/five.php"
},
{
ID: "6",
Photo: ”16323120/six.php"
}
]
}`

The urls work btw. I just dont want to give the correct url-links here publicly.

Comment: Do each of those urls actually return a unique image?

Comment: I get 6 rows now in the listview. I am supposed to get 2 rows as I have 6 images in my DB

Comment: see my edit - there should be else between the if statements